# CMake - How to inherit static library includes and dependencies?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm going to link my static library to some additional dependencies (which are installed in the system) then use this library, but my IDE says "No such file or directory" on inherited includes, like this:

CMakeLists.txt of my library:

```
find_package(lib1 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${MY_MEGA_LIB_NAME} lib1::lib1)
target_include_directories(${MY_MEGA_LIB_NAME} PUBLIC ${LIB1_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_package(lib2 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${MY_MEGA_LIB_NAME} lib2::lib2)
target_include_directories(${MY_MEGA_LIB_NAME} PUBLIC ${LIB2_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

CMakeLists.txt of project which uses my library:

```
find_library(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/ MyMegaLib.a)
target_include_directories(${MY_MEGA_PROJECT} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/MyMegaLib}
```

Errors are like this:

```
fatal error: lib1.h: No such file or directory
 #include <lib1.h>
```

What should I do to inherit includes properly?

_
Full hierarchy of my libraries and executables:

```
pre-lib1, pre-lib2
^^
lib1 (installed at the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX path)
^
MyMegaLib (static library)
^
MyProject(static library and an executable MyProject_tests)
```

So actually I'm getting errors about pre-lib1 and pre-lib2 about RE2 headers (prelib1.h : no such file or directory, preli2.h : no such file or directory) when I'm trying to cmake' MyProject_tests.

Comment: I don't know about to get these properties to inherit across cmake projects.  To use a library that was built outside a cmake project simply use the `target_link_libraries` and `target_include_directories`. Are you sure `target_include_directories(${MY_MEGA_PROJECT} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/MyMegaLib}` is pointing to the correct directory that contains all the required header files?  Also you have typos in this command it needs to at least be `target_include_directories(${MY_MEGA_PROJECT} PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/MyMegaLib)`.  `find_library` is also wrong syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, in my project it's the `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` call that pulls in the things exported in the library - don't you have something like that in your case? 
Something like:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${MY_MEGA_PROJECT} ${MY_MEGA_LIB_NAME})
```

But this is when specifying include directories/libraries inside the same CMake run.

When you want to reuse a library build in another CMake run, you probably have to [import/export these targets](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/Exporting-and-Importing-Targets) and their include directories/library dependencies etc. Libraries which do that typically generate some .cmake files in their build/install directories which provide these targets.

Comment: I am linking library to my project (which is library too) exactly as you wrote, and the problem is still here.

Comment: You didn't show it that's why I thought that was the reason ;). I'm doing this in the same CMake configuration run - are you cmake'ing your library and your project in a different cmake run? then there might be additional steps required (but I'm unfortunately out of my depth as to what those might be...)

Comment: Finally added full hierarchy description in post, please look

Comment: Updated my answer as well (though I can't give you specifics on this export/import procedure unfortunately)! Hope this helps...